# How to efficiently calculate path lengths in tree topology?

Tags: r

I have a number of structural models of trees (as in trees with wood, not statistical trees).  These models can be represented by simple data frames, with each row representing one branch segment, and containing information about that segment's length and parent row.  E.g.:

```
len    parent_row
.3    0
.4    1
.2    2
.5    1
...
```

I need to calculate the path length at least to each tip, but probably just as easily, at each "node" or branch end.

I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way of doing this than for-looping through the segments?  The example below runs quickly enough, but when running across thousands of segments and hundreds of trees, it takes hours/days.  I tried recursing, and while elegant, is horribly slow.  Better solutions than mine below are much appreciated!

Thanks,
Allie

```
calc_pathlen <- function(tree_structure) {
  tree_structure[1,]$path_len = tree_structure[1,]$len
  for (this_row in 2:nrow(tree_structure)) {
    prev_len = tree_structure[ tree_structure[this_row,]$parent_row, ]$path_len
    tree_structure[this_row,]$path_len = tree_structure[this_row,]$len + prev_len
  }
  return(tree_structure)
}

treestr = 
structure(list(len = c(2.3083, 1.632, 1.5825, 1.5592, 1.4847, 
1.367, 1.3112, 1.3211, 1.4324, 1.295, 1.1503, 0.989, 0.8525, 
0.9726, 0.8982, 0.8836, 0.8605, 0.7188, 0.5755, 0.5589, 0.6966, 
0.6531, 0.6741, 0.7582, 0.817, 0.7074, 0.7248, 0.5725, 0.6796, 
0.405, 0.5567, 0.6619, 0.473, 0.3485, 0.3946, 0.3593, 0.6572, 
0.3869, 0.4623, 3.4597, 0.5878, 0.7538, 0.3745, 2.3949, 0.3239, 
2.2521, 0.7563, 6.6197, 1.026, 0.9864, 0.6527, 0.6708, 0.4002, 
0.5858, 1.3728, 0.4469, 0.3309, 0.7075, 0.7637, 0.8429, 0.9874, 
0.1311, 0.3487, 1.037, 0.9087, 0.8871, 1.0236, 0.4481, 0.5124, 
0.4371, 0.4766, 0.4553, 0.5172, 0.4781, 0.5084, 0.4263, 0.3542, 
0.3062, 0.2901, 0.2042, 0.3126, 0.2366, 0.2714, 0.2741, 0.3511, 
0.1613, 0.3028, 0.1689, 0.0417, 0.2132, 0.1269, 0.2181, 0.1868, 
0.1553, 0.1151, 0.1602, 0.1786, 0.1649, 0.1967, 0.1584, 0.1366, 
0.13, 0.1722, 0.1725, 0.111, 0.1752, 0.1306, 0.1582, 0.0942, 
0.041, 0.356, 0.1958, 0.1212, 0.4129, 0.3499, 0.1706, 0.4647, 
0.272, 0.4036, 0.0949, 0.1161, 0.1271, 0.2153, 0.1685, 0.181, 
0.1302, 0.1229, 0.1146, 0.1393, 0.1722, 0.2033, 0.099, 0.1988, 
0.1264, 0.1377, 0.1634, 0.2223, 0.1466, 0.1376, 0.1788, 0.1946, 
0.1146, 0.2983, 0.1176, 0.0951, 0.1279, 0.095, 0.1909, 0.162, 
0.1562, 0.1225, 0.1471, 0.1976, 0.2194, 0.1256, 0.2105, 0.1147, 
0.1855, 0.1011, 0.1735, 0.1254, 0.1793, 0.8308, 0.2481, 0.2479, 
0.1788, 0.2907, 0.2904, 0.3411, 0.224, 0.2298, 0.1942, 0.1872, 
0.3311, 0.2295, 0.1466, 4.4547, 0.553, 0.2382, 0.2559, 0.2991, 
0.3763, 0.117, 0.2036, 0.1795, 0.1933, 0.1765, 0.3909, 0.4619, 
2.5901, 0.2655, 0.5306, 0.6369, 0.478, 2.5033, 0.4954, 0.2455, 
0.3417, 0.0605, 0.4264, 0.4569, 0.3266, 0.0666, 0.2642, 0.3017, 
0.0154, 0.3844, 0.2846, 0.2823, 0.3533, 0.1624, 0.1551, 0.1903, 
0.169, 0.1362, 0.1714, 0.1899, 0.1539, 0.1477, 0.1815, 0.2597, 
0.1302, 0.225, 0.3408, 0.2535, 0.521, 0.2328, 0.2115, 0.2387, 
0.1519, 0.1885, 0.1678, 0.1398, 0.3438, 0.458, 0.197, 0.2821, 
0.3694, 0.2039, 0.1518, 0.2985, 1.2251, 0.3328, 0.1593, 0.2945, 
0.1412, 0.2308, 0.2833, 2.6558, 0.3388, 0.3979, 0.2965, 0.2548, 
3.4452, 0.1267, 0.1801, 0.1494, 0.4831, 2.552, 0.1391, 0.3995, 
0.2753, 0.4019, 0.39, 0.7409, 0.5362, 0.7483, 1.6991, 0.2951, 
0.389, 0.7077, 0.7083, 0.6922, 0.5679, 0.2076, 0.2729, 0.3376, 
0.2368, 0.1639, 0.1788, 0.1885, 0.2328, 0.2057, 0.2091, 0.2673, 
0.1848, 0.1389, 0.1879, 0.1537, 0.3528, 0.2515, 0.2249, 0.259, 
0.1838, 0.2231, 0.228, 0.1753, 0.267, 0.2278, 0.257), parent_row = c(0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 
54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 8L, 11L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 
67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 
80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 17L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 
93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 
105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 
116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 
127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 
138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 
149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 
160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 
171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 
182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 
193L, 194L, 195L, 13L, 197L, 13L, 199L, 16L, 201L, 17L, 203L, 
204L, 19L, 206L, 207L, 22L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 
215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 
226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 
237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 
248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 
259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 
270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 22L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 280L, 
281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 22L, 286L, 287L, 23L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 
292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 299L), path_len = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("len", 
"parent_row", "path_len"), row.names = c(NA, 300L), class = "data.frame")

calc_pathlen(treestr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ideal case for `Rcpp`.

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('

  NumericVector calcTreeLength(NumericVector len, NumericVector idx){
    int n = len.size();
    NumericVector res(n);
    double cumsum=0;
    int j;
    res[0] = len[0];

    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
      j = idx[ i ] - 1;
      cumsum = res[ j ] + len[ i ];
      res[ i ] = cumsum;
    }
  return res;
}' )
```

Run two functions to compare results

```
treestr <- calc_pathlen(treestr)
treestr$path_len_cpp <- calcTreeLength(treestr$len, treestr$parent_row)

sum(treestr$path_len_cpp!=treestr$path_len)
#[1] 0
```

Speed difference is about ~3000 times

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  calc_pathlen(treestr), 
  calcTreeLength(treestr$len, treestr$parent_row)
)
```

[image]

Enjoy!